# Creating dynamic Spinner in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner

I want to create Three spinner. In first Spinner, I have to display countries name and according to selection of country name, I have to load the state name of that country in second Spinner and according to selection of state, I have to load cities name of that state in Third Spinner. Can any one post any example and please suggest which technique is better defining spinner data in Java or Xml.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, locations);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
s.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Label -->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dip"
    android:text="@string/lblAcc" />

<!-- Spinner Dropdown -->

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:entries="@array/acc_type" />

<!-- Select Label -->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dip"
    android:text="@string/lblSubAcc" />

<!-- Spinner Dropdown -->
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
/>
```

Resource xml should be like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">Spinner Example</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="lblAcc">Select Account Type</string>
<string name="lblSubAcc">Select Account Head</string>

<string-array name="acc_type">
    <item>Income</item>
    <item>Expense</item>
</string-array>

</resources>
```

And the Java class to use

```
public class SpinnerEx4Activity extends Activity implements
OnItemSelectedListener{
Spinner s1,s2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner_ex4);
    s1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    s2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String sp1= String.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem());
    Toast.makeText(this, sp1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(sp1.contentEquals("Income")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Salary");//You should add items from db here (first spinner)

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
          dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
    if(sp1.contentEquals("Expense")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Conveyance");//you should add items from db here(2nd spinner)

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
          dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
    }

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

With if else ladder you can add more spinner like 3rd spinner depending on 2nd one and so on.

Comment: I want to maintain the array of cities name. can you suggest where should i maintain either in xml or in java. or should i call it from directly database.?

Comment: If its dynamic you should maintain database. But if its not dynamic do it in java. So that you can control things in code. Need not to move to xml to change things always. @PratikSule